# How to make a Spectrogram chart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

I need to make spectrogram chart in flutter application.

Let me know how we can achieve the spectrogram chart in flutter application.

Here is the attached image of the chart which I need to achieve

[image: Spectrogram Chart]

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal solution, but because my project required tflite anyway, I ended up using [tflite-models-audioset-yamnet](https://github.com/antonyharfield/tflite-models-audioset-yamnet). After some slight modifications to [convert.py](https://github.com/antonyharfield/tflite-models-audioset-yamnet/blob/875dc6876b72c161c34c907b63fff35ce35fe56d/convert.py), I used this model in my flutter application to get the spectrogram arrays. At that point, I had to convert floats to uint8s, resize it to be an image shape, and used [ui.decodeImageFromPixels](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/decodeImageFromPixels.html) to display it.

---

(changes to the python function -- removed `predictions` from the `yamnet_frames_tflite_model` function and just call `model.save('spectrogram.tflite')` in the `main` before loading weights or converting the model)